# ios how to check if division remainder is integer

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

any of you knows how can I check if the division remainder is integer or zero?

```
if ( integer ( 3/2))
```

Comment: Use `%` modulo division, which gives the remainder.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should use the modulo operator like this

```
// a,b are ints
if ( a % b == 0) {
  // remainder 0
} else
{
  // b does not divide a evenly
}
```

Comment: I believe that Juan is trying to actually perform the division (including any decimal remainders) and determine if that result is an integer.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like what you are looking for is the modulo operator `%`, which will give you the remainder of an operation.

```
3 % 2 // yields 1
3 % 1 // yields 0
3 % 4 // yields 1
```

However, if you want to actually perform the division first, you may need something a bit more complex, such as the following:

```
//Perform the division, then take the remainder modulo 1, which will
//yield any decimal values, which then you can compare to 0 to determine if it is
//an integer
if((a / b) % 1 > 0))
{
    //All non-integer values go here
}
else
{
    //All integer values go here
}
```

Walkthrough

```
(3 / 2) // yields 1.5
1.5 % 1 // yields 0.5
0.5 > 0 // true
```

Comment: My question is who to know if the remainder is integer or zero. for example  3/2 the reminder is not zero or integer

Comment: I tried:     if ((10%2)% 1 > 0)
    {
        NSLog( @"reminder of %d", (10/2) );
    } but doesn't work

Comment: @RionWilliams That is clever!

Comment: @Juan, I am not terribly familiar with Xcode (or Objective-C) but I will look into it some more for you.

Comment: @Juan, could this be an issue with how decimals need to be formatted when outputted through NSLog?

Comment: (a / b) % 1 yields 0 consistently if and b are ints.  1.5 % 1 won't compile

Answer (score 0):

swift 3:

```
if a.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: b) == 0 {
    //All integer values go here
}else{
    //All non-integer values go here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to know which type of instance it is.

```
var val = 3/2
var integerType = Mirror(reflecting: val)

if integerType.subjectType == Int.self {
  print("Yes, the value is an integer")
}else{
  print("No, the value is not an integer")
}
```

let me know if the above was useful.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

```
if numberOne.isMultiple(of: numberTwo) { ... }
```

**Swift 4 or less**

```
if numberOne % numberTwo == 0 { ... }
```

Answer (score -1):

Swift 2.0

```
print(Int(Float(9) % Float(4)))   // result 1
```